# Image Saving Algorithm in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am implementing an ImageEditor control in Xamarin Android. I have an ImageView in which the Image is loaded from the gallery. I have added the ImageView in a FrameLayout (say: MainLayout). I have added another view which holds new shapes and texts I add on top of the MainLayout (ie:, MainLayout has two children on top ImageView and ShapeView). For saving the changes,I have converted the MainLayout to bitmap and saved in sd card. But the issue is that since the whole MainLayout is getting saved, the empty space for the ImageView after image loaded is also getting saved along. How can I cut the space for the Image alone and save.

PS: My ShapeView has the same size as the loaded image

Any Help is appreciated.

Regards,
Nitish

My Saving Algorithm is as below:

```
Bitmap ViewToBitmap(View view)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(view.Width, view.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.Draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
 void Save()
 {
      var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(file.ToString(), "Image" + 
        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".png");
      var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
      bitmap = ViewToBitmap(this);
      bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
      stream.Close();
  }
```

Comment: How about saving the `ImageView` and `ShapeView` separatly?

Comment: I have done that now using the below code
`private Bitmap GetBitmapFromView(ImageView imageView)
        {
            imageView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
            imageView.BuildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageView.Drawable).Bitmap;
            return bitmap;
        }`

`mExtractedImage = GetBitmapFromView(ImageView);
bitmap = ViewToBitmap(ShapeVIew);`

Comment: After that using the below code, I merge the bitmaps
`'JoinBitmaps(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)
{
     newBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, config);
            Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
            newCanvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap1,new Matrix(), null);
            newCanvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap2,0,0,null);
}`

Comment: But the issue I am facing now is that the ImageSize changes differently. Image I used in around 4MB and while saving it shoots to 12MB.
I have compressed the image with the below code:
`JoinBitmaps.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, mStream);`

Comment: Any help on how to reduce the size of the saved image without loss of quality and resolution